# Insert Statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to insert the values ('testu', 'testp', 'testname', 'testsur', 'testemail') into [dbo].[users]

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and anytime i try to query something like

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[users]
VALUES ('testu', 'testp', 'testname', 'testsur', 'testemail')
```

I get an Error on the "INSERT" statement saying: This statement is not recognized in the context. What does this mean? How can i fix it?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[users] (
    [username] VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
    [password] VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
    [name]     VARCHAR (40)  NOT NULL,
    [surname]  VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
    [email]    VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([username] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Do you execute this statement with Management Studio and with the correct database selected?

Comment: Sounds like you have the 'master' DB or at least the *wrong* database selected.

Comment: that fixed it, but when i run the code it says
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: That sounds like one of your columns is limited in character length. You should edit your original post with the column data (name, data type and length).

Comment: hopefully you are not storing plaintext passwords....

Comment: Do you have any triggers on the table (e.g., that encrypt the password)?

Comment: As tested on [SQLFiddle (*click here*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/80817/1), you DDL and DML works fine.

Comment: Please use the (unfortunately) optional clause that specifies the columns you're inserting *into*.  That's not your problem here (assuming that your table creation statement is accurate) but it will be a problem next time you add columns to the table.

Comment: Mitch Wheat, this is just a very horrible test Database i am using to familiarize myself with using T-SQL with C#, i will use something way more secure than plaintext for the passwords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am running your statement in a database by the name **[TestDB]**

```
USE [TestDB]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[users] 
(
    [username] VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
    [password] VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
    [name]     VARCHAR (40)  NOT NULL,
    [surname]  VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
    [email]    VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([username] ASC)
);

GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[users] VALUES ('testu', 'testp', 'testname', 'testsur', 'testemail')
```

The result after running the above statement

[image]

Next I will try to insert another row to the table as under

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[users] VALUES ('testuwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww', 'testp', 'testname', 'testsur', 'testemail')
```

Result is

[image]

Which is an error that indicates that the [UserName] column value length is more than the length specified while the DDL was created.

**Solution**

A) Either limit the [UserName] length within 40 characters (in this example).

B) Or Increase the length of the [UserName] column by using the **ALTER** statement.

e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[users]
ALTER COLUMN [username] VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL
```

N.B.~ here [username] column has just taken as a reference to point the error. This situation can happen for other columns also. So just verify for which column it is happening.

Comment: but the error states that `This statement is not recognized in the context.` not `String or binary would be truncated`

Comment: The USE [TestDB] should fix that